# Создание массива битов

Tags: java

Мне нужно создать массив битов фиксированного размера 32. Изначально все биты должны быть 0, но потом некоторые из них мне нужно будет менять по индексу  на 1, и проверять изменилось ли значение. Как это можно сделать пробовал использовать Bitset но возможно это можно сделать лучше.

Comment: Можно просто использовать битовые операции со значением типа int.

Comment: Чем не устраивает BitSet? Напишите, чтобы ответ мог учесть причины, по которым вам не годится BitSet.

Comment: На самом деле все устраивает, я делаю фильтр блюма. Но я прочитал что этот класс устаревший и стало интересно как можно сделать лучше)

Answer (score 1):

Массив битов размера 32  можно хранить в обычном `int` - у него размерность позволяет. Изменять бит по индексу можно так

```java
int value = 0;
int index = 10;
value = value | 1 << index; // value = 1024
```

сбросить бит можно так

```java
int value = 32;
int index = 5;
value = value & ~(1 << index); // value = 0
```